# Remove file from remote using streaming inbound channel adapter spring boot implementation

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to remove file from remote by implementing streaming inbound but connection is closing before adviceChain implementing.

**CODE:**

```
@Bean
    public SessionFactory<LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
        factory.setHost(sftpHost);
        factory.setPort(sftpPort);
        factory.setUser(sftpUser);
        factory.setPassword(sftpPwd);
        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        return new CachingSessionFactory<LsEntry>(factory);
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "stream", poller = @Poller(cron = "2 * * * * ?"))
    public MessageSource<InputStream> sftpMessageSource() {
        SftpStreamingMessageSource messageSource = new SftpStreamingMessageSource(template());
        messageSource.setRemoteDirectory(remoteDirecotry);
        messageSource.setFilter(new AcceptAllFileListFilter<>());
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public SftpRemoteFileTemplate template() {
         return new SftpRemoteFileTemplate(sftpSessionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    @Transformer(inputChannel = "stream", outputChannel = "data")
    public org.springframework.integration.transformer.Transformer transformer() {
        return new StreamTransformer("UTF-8");
    }


    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "data" ,adviceChain = "afterChain")
    @Bean
    public MessageHandler handler() {

        return new MessageHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {

                String fileName = message.getHeaders().get("file_remoteFile").toString();               
                if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(message.toString())) {

                else{
                    log.info("No file found in the Remote location");
                }

            }
        };
    }




        @Bean
        public ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice afterChain() {

            ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
            advice.setOnSuccessExpression(
                    "@template.remove(headers['file_remoteDirectory'] + headers['file_remoteFile'])");
            //advice.setOnSuccessExpressionString("@template.remove(headers['file_remoteFile'])");
            advice.setPropagateEvaluationFailures(true);
            return advice;

        }
```

wherever i search every one is suggesting to implement ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice but it is throwing me below error.

```
        2018-03-27 12:32:02.618  INFO 23216 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=starsBatchJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{JobID=1522168322277}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
    2018-03-27 12:32:02.618  INFO 23216 --- [ask-scheduler-1] c.f.u.config.ParentBatchConfiguration    : Job Status Completed
    2018-03-27 12:32:02.618  INFO 23216 --- [ask-scheduler-1] c.f.u.config.ParentBatchConfiguration    : Total time tokk for Stars Batch execution: 0 seconds.
    2018-03-27 12:32:02.618  INFO 23216 --- [ask-scheduler-1] c.f.u.config.ParentBatchConfiguration    : Batch Job lock is released
    2018-03-27 12:32:02.633  INFO 23216 --- [ask-scheduler-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : Disconnecting from hpchd1e.hpc.ford.com port 22
    2018-03-27 12:32:02.633 ERROR 23216 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Dispatcher failed to deliver Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to remove file: 2: No such file; nested exception is 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem.  My path to the remote file was incorrect. I needed a trailing `/`. It is a little difficult to see since the path is being created inside a Spel Expression.  You can see the path using the following in the `handleMessage()` method.

```
String remoteDirectory = (String) message.getHeaders().get("file_remoteDirectory");
String remoteFile = (String) message.getHeaders().get("file_remoteFile");
```

I did have to use the `advice.setOnSuccessExpressionString("@template.remove(headers['file_remoteFile'])");` that is commented out above instead of `advice.setOnSuccessExpression"@template.remove(headers['file_remoteDirectory'] + headers['file_remoteFile'])");`
It is incorrect in the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-streaming which is why I believe people who struggle with this lose faith in the doc. But this seems to be the only error.

Comment: Works for me: Note '/' ... advice.setOnSuccessExpressionString("@template.remove(headers['file_remoteDirectory'] + '/' + headers['file_remoteFile'])");